# jquery setting timout before loading a window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I am working on a webapp in spring on which i would like to insert a timer that would reset everytime the user press a button.

Basically the webpage display a number of rows containing data from a database, each rows are for a different records.

When the user press a button it change the status of the record from draft to 'pending approval'. then reload the entire page.

Because it may happen that a user has to change the status 100 rows and it can take a couple of seconds to reload the page each time, i would like to set a timer after it change the status of the record and before it reloads the page.

The code below does set a timeout but my problem is that 5 seconds after the button is pressed the page reload, even if many rows had the button pressed.

```
    function submitDraft(pId) {
    $.getJSON("putInProcess.do", { id: pId }, function(data) {
        // display the message
        fadeInMsg(data.code, '', data.msg);

        if (data.code == 0) {
            $("#"+pId).remove();

            // relocate to the main page
            setTimeout(function() {
                delayWindowLoad(data.name);
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way to reset the timeout back to 0 if the user press the button again?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can store a reference to the setTimeout()

```
var timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                delayWindowLoad(data.name);
            }, 5000);
```

Then call clearTimeout on that reference.

`window.clearTimeout(timeout)`;

In your click event call everytime the clearTimeout, and then define your timeout again.

Look at this fiddle I hoppe it helps.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eddiarnoldo/Anzqn/)

Comment: Thank you Eduardo, this is exactly what i was looking for.
Being still a beginner in jquery i did not think it was that simple.

Comment: Yw I'm glad I could help you

Answer (score 1):

```
var timer;
function submitDraft(pId) {
```

and

```
if (timer) window.clearTimeout(timer);  //if we have another timeout, cancel it
timer = setTimeout(function() {         //store it into a variable so we can reference it
    delayWindowLoad(data.name);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Sorry about not choosing your answer, i just notice that altough you answered before Eduardo, you answered before him. if i could id give it to each of you.

Comment: And the code sample posted in that answer would be wrong if you used var as suggested.

Comment: @epascarello what do you mean?